# How to learn spoken English from audio books?

Tags: spoken-english

My written English is fine. Now I have gotten audio books to listen to for improving spoken English.

I wish to know whether I need to pause every once in a while to write down what I hear in order to remember it?

Would that be useful for learning spoken English?
How should I make the most of these audio books?

Comment: Are you reading the book along with the audio?

Comment: @galacticcowboy no, do I need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that learning styles vary among people. What works for many is listening and reading at the same time. This is probably why there are so many videos of language lessons (e.g. on You tube and elsewhere), that have subtitles in the language you are trying to learn (that is, you can read exactly what you hear). This is no hard evidence, of course, but the fact that this sort of learning material is widespread might indicate that there are a lot of people who find it useful.

In your case, finding a printed version of the audio books you have could be helpful. For some, silently opening your mouth with the speaker/actor, while looking at the text, helps improve pronunciation. I know it seems a bit funny, but it won't hurt to try it.

For spoken language, conversation is very important. Audio books are great, but if you could discuss what you listened to with someone, it would do wonders for your spoken English.

Answer (score 2):

Learning is a very personal thing, and each of us learns differently. Similarly, one person might remember directly from audio, and another may need to write it down. Luckily, you don't need to write anything down for written English! Grab a long audio-book, listen to it once, and see how much you can improve. Since pronunciation is a large part of spoken English, you'll soon get used to it, especially if you listen to it multiple times.

Good luck!